# Problema con bootstrap y agregar estilos nuevos

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap

Tengo un proyecto con bootstrap y no sé cómo agregarle un nuevo estilo de checkbox.

Ya tengo descargado los archivos, pero no sé dónde agregarlos en el proyecto ni cómo hacer uso del los estilos. Es en Visual studio Asp.Net

Comment: Si recién estás iniciando con ASP.net MVC te recomiendo ver este workshop que hice desde cero: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Comment: Tomas, por favor revisa: [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Debes proveer mas información para que la comunidad te ayude.

Answer (score 2):

Asegurate de que llamas a tus estilos después de llamar a los de Bootstrap para que los estilos que intentes modificar se sobrescriban

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Tema opcional -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- Mi hoja de estilos -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Si lo pones al contrario parecerá que tus estilos no se están aplicando, pero solo es que los de Bootstrap están sobrescribiendo los tuyos

Answer (score 2):

Sumado a las respuestas anteriores, te recomiendo un [toggle](https://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switch/) para que se vea mejor gráficamente.

Acá un ejemplo (también en [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rt79Loue/)):

```html
<!-- Toggle Switch -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/css-toggle-switch/latest/toggle-switch.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- HTML -->
<label class="switch-light switch-candy">
  <input type="checkbox">

  <strong>
    Checkbox
  </strong>

  <span>
    <span>Apagado</span>
    <span>Encendido</span>
    <a></a>
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Hola @PauloUrbano. Una respuesta de este estilo se podría beneficiar enormemente con un pequeño fragmento de código que ejemplifique su uso. Aún cuando el enlace que publicaste tenga el recurso, es mucho más efectivo cuando la respuesta incluye un ejemplo (dejando el enlace como referencia para más información). Pensemos que muchos no siguen los enlaces y a todos nos gusta ver respuestas completas, de calidad, en las que no haya que ir a otra url para entender qué se está respondiendo.

Comment: edité tu respuesta agregando el ejemplo que pusiste en el enlace, de la forma a la que me refería. Considerá usar el botón de Snippets en cualquier respuesta de JavaScript/HTML/CSS en el futuro, ya que le suman calidad a la misma.

Comment: Agradecido colega, soy nuevo en el foro.. ya me acostumbraré a publicar de mejor forma las respuestas :)

Answer (score 0):

Debes de copiar los archivos en la carpeta `Content`, si se trata de un proyecto MVC, para utilizarlos debes incluirlos en la vista `_Layout` para que estén disponible en todas las paginas que utilicen ese `Layout`, si solo ocupas el estilo en algunas paginas lo mas recomendable es que los agregues solo en estas.

Para utlizar un estilo la forma mas secilla es con el tag

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="ruta/al/styles.css">`

si el estilo consta de varios archivos lo mas recomendable es realizar un [bundle](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) 
En youtube hay varios tutoriales sobre el tema, podrias ver [este](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhhVicqyi1U)